# Equivalent to a qualify statement in mysql/laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a database that looks like this:

```
ID |   facebook_id  | likes | created_at
--------------------------------------------------
 1 |      x         | 100   | 2017-01-01 12:10:15
 2 |      x         | 110   | 2017-01-02 12:10:15
 3 |      y         | 115   | 2017-01-01 12:10:15
 4 |      y         | 120   | 2017-01-02 12:10:15
 5 |      z         | 200   | 2017-01-01 12:10:15
 6 |      z         | 201   | 2017-01-01 12:10:15
 7 |      z         | 200   | 2017-02-02 12:10:15
 8 |      z         | 205   | 2017-02-03 12:10:15
 9 |      z         | 250   | 2017-03-04 12:10:15
```

I want to get the latest record for each of the unique `facebook_id`'s in the table then order it by `likes` in `descending` order. I am using [laravel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4) and [mysql](https://www.mysql.com/) for the database. In [teradata](http://forgetcode.com/Teradata/1778-RANK) I would do something like

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY facebook_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) = 1
```

to order the results by `facebook_id` and get the latest row by unique facebook_id. But I'm not sure how to do this in laravel/mysql.

I have tried

```
Database::select('facebook_id', 'likes', 'created_at')
          ->orderBy('likes', 'desc')
          ->distinct('facebook_id')
          ->latest('created_at')
          ->limit(20)
          ->get();
```

But it just orders it by `likes` and doesnt get me unique `facebook_id`'s

My results are:

```
Top Profile ID: z Likes:250
Top Profile ID: z Likes:205
Top Profile ID: z Likes:201
Top Profile ID: z Likes:200
```

What I want to get is:

```
Top Profile ID: z Likes:250
Top Profile ID: y Likes:120
Top Profile ID: x Likes:110
```

Comment: There is no equivalent to `qualify` because there are no window functions.  I might suggest that you ask another question, including the teradata query (or a simplified version) and asking how to write it in MySQL.

Comment: Try: 

Database::select('facebook_id', 'likes', 'created_at')
          ->orderBy('likes', 'desc')
           ->get()
           ->unique('facebook_id');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question:

> I want to get the latest record for each of the unique facebook_id's
>   in the table then order it by likes in descending order.

has an answer.  There are multiple methods.  Here is one:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.created_at = (select max(t2.create_at)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.facebook_id = t.facebook_id
                     )
order by t.likes desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just needed a `groupBy` on `facebook_id` on your query

```
->groupBy('facebook_id')
```